# My PHP code not running properly?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some issues here. I'm trying to make a query to get data from a website database, however the query returns no rows even though I know that they exist. The vars `$uslog` and `$ushas` are the username and hash code of each user, in this case my test user which is 'PixelKnight1398' and '1398'  The cookies are saved as such.  When I try to run the MySQL code in phpMyAdmin it works perfectly fine, but in this sense it doesn't work.  I'm not sure what's going wrong if it's a syntax error or I am just stupid.  Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

```
$uslog = cure($_COOKIE['userloggedin']);
$ushas = cure($_COOKIE['uservalue']);
function cure($data) { 
  $data = trim($data); 
  $data = stripslashes($data); 
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data); 
  return $data; 
}
$query = "SELECT friends FROM `memberHandler` WHERE `username`='$uslog' AND `hash`='$ushas'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 1){
    die("Could not find user match");
}
```

Comment: Please read up about SQL injection

Comment: Try ``$uslog = "Dorian'; DROP TABLE `friends`; --"`` ... and `echo $query;` instead of executing it. ;-)

Comment: Btw.: Formattings like `htmlspecialchars` should be done before HTML output, not before storing into database, since there could come up situations, where you will need the raw data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to be more security aware with your query and should be using bound variables with a PDO based query. You also need to have the variables as below - with concatentation and double quotes:

```
 $query = "SELECT friends FROM `memberHandler` WHERE `username`=' " . $uslog . " ' AND `hash`=' " . $ushas . " ' ";
```

and if you are using bound parameters it would be :

```
$query = "SELECT friends FROM `memberHandler` WHERE `username`=:uslog  AND `hash`= :ushas ";
```

and then you would bind the bound variables as (note the absence of other portions of code since the op does not use PDO)

```
$query -> bindValue(":uslog  " , $uslog  , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query -> bindValue(":ushas" , $ushas, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: `mysqli` does provide prepared statements as well.

Comment: What is wrong with procedural queries?  And I don't want to say that the first query you gave me didn't work but I tried that, and then tried messing with the quotes and what not and it still didn't work.

Comment: thanks @Quasimodo's clone - havent used mysqli significantly - I jumped from the old mysql queries to PDO and only use that now. Cheers :))

Comment: @DorianWaite There's nothing "wrong" with procedural syntax. Some people consequently prefer OOP since it is better encapsulated. There's only something wrong with injecting insecure user data (cookies) directly into SQL. Lookup SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I have a function:
`function cure($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
 }`
which I will use on the cookies to help prevent SQL injection as I am aware what it is.  My main concern on the other hand is trying to figure out why my query as well as the procedural query that was provided in this answer aren't working =/

Comment: @DorianWaite There is a built function `mysqli_real_escape_string` doing that more secure based on the connection settings. However, there could be done some attack in conjunction with encoding attacks in few situations anyway. Also PDO isn't 100% sure when falling back to emulated prepared statement. Real prepared statements as also given with `mysqli` library is the most secure form performing queries based on external data input.